Android Studio Checkbox
I am currently confused on an issue that I am having in Android Studio with a Checkbox. I have a ViewHolder that contains a checkbox that seems to be going down to the True path, even though it is returning false when I debug. Any ideas of where to start looking because I have never had this issue before. Below is an example of the code. I tried with button.ischecked() and isChecked == true, just to run into the same issue. Any help is appreciated.
holder.chkCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                    String str = "True";
                    // your code to checked checkbox
                } else {
                    String str = "False";
                    // your code to  no checked checkbox
                }
            }
    });

I was expecting to return false and true when it was supposed to.

Make sure to  check if any other code is changing the CheckBox's state programmatically.
You can try something like this before your code so that you can detect the change state.
holder.chkCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    private boolean isListenerTriggered = false;

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
        if (!isListenerTriggered) {
            isListenerTriggered = true;
            if (isChecked) {
                String str = "True";
                // your code to checked checkbox
            } else {
                String str = "False";
                // your code to no checked checkbox
            }
        }

        isListenerTriggered = false;
    }
});


Learn to use markdown to format your posts.

this issue likely stems from RecyclerViwe recycling views and reusing checkbox states
holder.chkCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
holder.chkCheck.setChecked(item.isChecked());
holder.chkCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);

